# Error when calling catkin_make --> Invoking "make" failed'

Tags: catkin-make, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm new to ROS. I was following exactly the steps listed here:
http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/ROS_packages_and_contents_required_to_teleoperate_the_iRobot_Create

However, when I run catkin_make, i got the following error:

```
user@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/user/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/user/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/user/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/user/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/user/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/user/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/user/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  3%] [  3%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Generating dynamic reconfigure files from cfg/TurtleBot.cfg: /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/include/irobotcreate_node/TurtleBotConfig.h /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/irobotcreate_node/cfg/TurtleBotConfig.py
../catkin_generated/env_cached.sh: 16: exec: /home/user/catkin_ws/src/irobotcreate_node/cfg/TurtleBot.cfg: Permission denied
make[2]: *** [/home/user/catkin_ws/devel/include/irobotcreate_node/TurtleBotConfig.h] Error 126
make[1]: *** [irobotcreate_node/CMakeFiles/irobotcreate_node_gencfg.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  3%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
user@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$
```

How do I solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206860/error-when-calling-catkin_make---%3E-invoking-%22make%22-failed%27/) by [JamesAngsy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21979/jamesangsy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add executable flag to the .cfg file:

```
cd /home/user/catkin_ws/src/irobotcreate_node/cfg/
chmod +x TurtleBot.cfg
```

Without the exec flag dynamic_reconfigure cannot created the reconfig headers....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JamesAngsy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21979/jamesangsy/) on 2015-04-08**:
Hi Wolf,

thanks for your reply. I did as you mentioned. but there's still error. The error is the same as above.

**Comment by [JamesAngsy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21979/jamesangsy/) on 2015-04-08**:
It works Wolf! thanks a lot!
I changed to small cap 'x'.--> chmod +x TurtleBot.cfg

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2015-04-09**:
thanks, updated the answer:)